# Remove extra br tags after specific count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string and would like to display only 2 `br` tags and after that remove all `br` tags.

```
text.replace(/<br><br><br>/g, '<br><br>')
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
text.replace(/(<br>)+/g, '<br><br>')
```

Comment: It looks for at least one, or more `br`'s and then replaces the matched group with 2 `br`'s.

Comment: yes this code is use when you have more then one br and wants to remove them with specific count.  in my case if there is more then 2 br then i replace them with 2 br's tag.  you can also replace this tag with another tags what ever you like.  ex. <br> tag to <b> tag.